# why use IDisposable when a dispose() method could be written in a class

Tags: c#, oop

Title explains the question quite clearly. I want to know why would I implement IDisposable interface that provides only one method definition in a class, where, in another class, I can explicitly define a dispose() method and release all unmanaged resources.

Say I have these two classes

```
class MyClass : IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose() { }
}

class MyClass2
{
    public void Dispose() { }
}
```

What exactly is the difference between MyClass and MyClass2??

Comment: Does it mean that its commonly a programming practice? @PradeepSimha

Comment: You use the interface to let the .Net know it has a Dispose Method to call when needed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A very concrete consequence in this example, specific to `IDisposable`, is that the first class can be used in a `using() {}` statement and the second one cannot:

```
using (var c1 = new MyClass())  { ... }  // Ok
using (var c2 = new MyClass2()) { ... }  // Error
```

The more general answer is that interfaces provide a contract that allows substitution. Search for 'the benefits of interfaces' or something like that for more information. For instance [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12328579/60761) has a list.

An example of substitution:

```
public interface IRepository { ... }

public class RealRepository : IRepository { ... }
public class MockRepository : IRepository { ... }

class MyController { public IRepository { get; set; }
```

This (sketchy) fragment shows a Controller that can be used with a real (Db) Repository and tested with a Mock Repository.

Comment: what do you mean by "that allows substitution". can you give me an example pelase?

Comment: I've added an example but SO questions are not the right place to get basic tutorials. See these [google results](https://www.google.nl/search?q=c%23+tutorial+interface&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a).

Answer (score 3):

Because `IDisposable` defines something of a universal contract of conventional semantics for freeing resources. It's a known pattern that can be relied upon to expose a relevant method that does a certain thing (Henk gives a specific example of this in the language with `using`). Nothing but the immediate user of your code knows of the existence of your class's `Dispose` method.

In your first instance, the class implements the contract, and can be used in a conventional way.

Comment: can you eleborate a bit further please? I know what are interfaces, but what exactly is the difference?

Comment: but an immediate user would also know the existence of class Dispose method by looking at the class definition. So what difference does it make?

Comment: @AtharAnis I think the idea is that any responsible third-party developer using your class will recognize that it is `IDisposable` and ensure to call its `Dispose` method when they're done with it. EDIT: It's not so much that it has a `Dispose` method so much as it _is_ `IDisposable`. If it doesn't inherit the interface, then the `Dispose` method could mean anything. Bottom line, .NET developers in general understand and adhere to principles working with `IDisposable` classes.

Comment: @AtharAnis Code can at least be 'genericised', such that you can check if a thing is disposable or not, whereas otherwise you would have to explicitly know, or use reflection to look up the relevant method. Also, without a contract specification, your 'custom' Dispose method could do anything!

Comment: @GrantThomas ok I got it so far, but say i implement IDisposable and inside its Dispose Method I don't dispose the unmanaged resources and instead generate new unmanaged resources. How would we justify that?

Comment: @AtharAnis You can't justify that, it's a misuse and irresponsible. With any contract comes a matter of trust.

Comment: @GrantThomas what do you mean by a contract? is it an agreement kind of a thing? and if it is, then how would I know what contract does IEnumerable has? and what i should be doing with methods exposed by IEnumerable interface?

Comment: You _can_ have an `IEnumerable` make changes (side effects) when iterating and cause all sorts of horrors with Linq. It doesn't mean you _should_. You _can_ have an `IDisposable` create unmanaged resources in its `Dispose` method, but it doesn't mean you _should_. You _can_ make implicit conversions throw exceptions, but it doesn't mean you _should_. I can only imagine if you did you might get a good talking to by your boss. .NET developers work against certain... "good behaviour" or culture in general because it makes sense and saves our sanity (usually).

Answer (score 1):

IDisposable is just one interface, but the question might be generalized "Why should I implement an interface when I can simply implement methods?". Here is another example which might shed some light: it matters when it comes to *consuming* the classes.

```
interface IAnimal
{
    void PutInZoo(Zoo);
}

class Cat: IAnimal
{
    public void PutInZoo(Zoo theZoo);
}

class Fish
{
   public void PutInZoo(Zoo theZoo);
}

class Zoo
{
    public void PutInZoo(IAnimal animal)
    {
         animal.PutInZoo(this);
    }

    public Zoo()
    {
         this.PutInZoo(new Cat());  // Ok
         this.PutInZoo(new Fish()); // Nope, Fish doesn't implement IAnimal
    }
}
```

The most prominent side effect of implementing an interface, aside from compilation errors, is that *if* the interface **changes** you *must* abide to it.

In this example, if `IAnimal` changes its definition and `PutInZoo` is renamed to `FreeFromZoo`, `Fish` would still compile (and probably break its consumers) but `Dog` won't: it no longer implements `IAnimal`.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between the two is just that Class1 *officially* implements the interface.

Class2 just potentially implements it, although these terms aren't great; the implementation/presence of the method may be the same for both.

Comment: thats what my point is! so why would i use IDisposable ? Offcourse, Microsoft must have developed it for some reason.

Comment: If your class is only used in one place, you're the only one that uses it, and these won't change, you can skip IDisposable.