# Why use IOrganizationService instead of CrmServiceClient in Dynamics 365 XRM tooling SDK?

Tags: c#, .net, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-365

Microsoft sample code for accessing Dynamics often looks like this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            string connectionString =
                "Url=https://myorg.crm.dynamics.com; Username=me@myorg.com; Password=******; authtype=Office365";

            using (CrmServiceClient conn = new CrmServiceClient(connectionString))
            {
                // Cast the proxy client to the IOrganizationService interface.
                IOrganizationService orgService = (IOrganizationService)conn.OrganizationWebProxyClient ??
                                                  conn.OrganizationServiceProxy;

                Console.WriteLine("Microsoft Dynamics CRM version {0}.", ((RetrieveVersionResponse)orgService.Execute(new RetrieveVersionRequest())).Version);
            }
        }
        catch (FaultException<OrganizationServiceFault> osFaultException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Fault Exception caught");
            Console.WriteLine(osFaultException.Detail.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Uncaught Exception");
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
    }
}
```

But it is equally possible (and simpler) to use the Crm Service Client directly, like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            string connectionString =
                "Url=https://myorg.crm.dynamics.com; Username=me@myorg.com; Password=******; authtype=Office365";

            using (CrmServiceClient conn = new CrmServiceClient(connectionString))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Microsoft Dynamics CRM version {0}.", ((RetrieveVersionResponse)conn.Execute(new RetrieveVersionRequest())).Version);
            }
        }
        catch (FaultException<OrganizationServiceFault> osFaultException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Fault Exception caught");
            Console.WriteLine(osFaultException.Detail.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Uncaught Exception");
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
    }
}
```

My question:  Why use that IOrganizationService property ever?  It seems as if it has only a subset of the functionality of the CrmServiceClient.  And CrmServiceClient used directly seems both faster, simpler, more efficient, and more feature-rich.

Any idea about why the sample code always has this additional layer of indirection?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`IOrganizationService` is an `interface` that defines the most basic methods required to access all Dynamics functions. There are a number of [general](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1389434/benefits-of-implementing-an-interface) [benefits](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/108240/why-are-interfaces-useful) to using interfaces.

`IOrganizationService` has been around since CRM 2011, whilst `CrmServiceClient` was introduced around CRM 2016. A simple reason for using `IOrganizationService` is that has been around much longer and is present in existing code bases.

`CrmServiceClient` implements `IOrganizationService`, and also provides a range of other methods, e.g. authenticating with CRM. Before `CrmServiceClient` was introduced we used `CrmConnection` to authenticate to CRM. When we had to migrate from `CrmConnection` to `CrmServiceClient`, we only had to change to `CrmServiceClient`, extract `IOrganizationService` and the rest of the code base remains the same.

Programming to the `IOrganizationService` interface makes your code far more portable, and reusable. For example; when you don't know your service object is going to be created.

```
IOrganizationService orgService = IOrganizationService)conn.OrganizationWebProxyClient ?? conn.OrganizationServiceProxy;
```

For testing purposes when you want to mock `IOrganizationService` with a new `MockOrganizationService` class.

When you want to move code between an external application and a plugin. In a plugin the `CrmServiceClient` is not provided.